# Extracting value from Posted JSON

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I'm trying to query using PHP.

I just expect the value to return to be a number but it's giving me back more:

```
    $numberCount = $this->db->query("SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE number = $number;");
    $numberCountResult = $numberCount->result();
    $this->set_response($numberCountResult, REST_Controller::HTTP_CREATED);
```

My API will now return me:

```
[
  {
    "count(*)": "1"
  }
]
```

I just want it to give me:

```
[
  {
    "1"
  }
]
```

How can I just extract that single value?

Comment: Try to pass the value of the array currently it taking both key and value, this might work (but not checked) $this->set_response($numberCountResult[1], REST_Controller::HTTP_CREATED); NOTICE: $numberCountResult[1]

Comment: Nope: 

    <p>Message:  Undefined offset: 1</p>
    <p>Filename: api/User.php</p>
    <p>Line Number: 33</p>

Comment: print $numberCountResult array by using print_r($numberCountResult) just to verify what it returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Description** To achieve this first use aliasing in your raw query as describe in the following code snippet and also make use of row() function for finding the query result.

**Code**

```
    $numberCount = $this->db->query("SELECT count(*) as number FROM users WHERE number = $number;");
    $row = $numberCount->row();

    if (isset($row)) {
        $numberCountResult = $row->numer;
    }
    $this->set_response($numberCountResult, REST_Controller::HTTP_CREATED);
```